# Dollar sign '$' in the output of whoami in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, windows-domain

It is a domain environment. There are several machines, connection to whom must be performed under user joined specific groups ("Super Manager Users" and "Super Admin Users"). But there is some issues with that membership.
I provided several tests:

Log in under that user (xyz\administrator) and issued

```
whoami /groups
```

On both machines the output is following:

```
ABC\machine $ Super Manager Users
ABC\machine $ Super Admin Users
```

Note, that there is a space between '$' and names. As I understand it means that user is member of that groups but groups are absent from local machine.
I know that DC holds $ at the end of usernames. But it seems to be another case.
All other groups are just as "normal"

Comment: You're example is confusing. :)   The domain in your example is "XYZ", so then, what's "ABC"?  And your example Whoami output doesn't match the structure of actual Whoami output (which would be 4 columns "Group Name", "Attributes", "Type", "SID").  Are you saying your problem is that your Group Names are showing as "ABC\machine $ Super Manager Users", instead of "XYZ\Super Manager Users"?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't copied sid and others. But you understand me right. I'm investigating the issue, so I can't describe the environment very detailed as I have no full access. The question is like you supposed

Comment: Makes more sense, but I'm still not sure I'm following it all.. :)  So, your domain is "XYZ", but it's actually showing the groups being part of domain "ABC"?  Do you have a domain trust with another domain named "ABC" or something?  Also what does "machine" represent in those group names, or does it actually just say "machine"?

Comment: It's just hostname. I suspect that it means that this user is in this groups but they actually locally absent on those PCs. And they exist in another domain only